# Cannot restore LIVE site to DEV environment

Tags: 2013, restore

Background: Live and Dev sites have been co-existing for years. My normal routine is to backup the Live environment site collection in Central Admin and restore it to the Dev environment using the following command

```
Restore-SPSite http://sitedev -path c:\LocationOfBackup -force
```

I started having problems doing this when the patches got our of synch between Live and Dev, so both systems were brought up to CU May 2018. Config wizard was run on all farm servers after upgrade, and the upgrade completed with no errors.

Problem: I now receive an error when I try to restore the Live site to Dev

```
Restore-SPSite: <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr></nativestack>
+CategoryInfo: InvalidData:...:[Restore-SPSite] DirectoryNotFoundEception
```

ULS logs seem to reference the following 3 things that sound potentially helpful:

1. DEBUG Error serializing, caller should rollback transaction and any intermediate changesco. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The instance of the SQL Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK resource at this time. Rerun your statement when there are fewer active users. Ask the database administrator to check the lock and memory configuration for this instance, or to check for long-running transactions.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError...
2. There is no Web named "/".
3. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 0x80070003, StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Delete(SPSiteDeleteFlags flags)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Delete()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Restore

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this? I'd really like to get my Dev environment back...

Comment: I had hit similar issue when restoring large site collection, how big is your backup and how much memory you have on SQL? It seems that restore operation needs to load the whole backup to memory before it can complete restore, I have workaround the issue by increasing the page file on SQL.

Comment: .bak file is just over 5GB and there is currently 1-2 GB of free Ram on the SQL server. I will increase the paging file size as you suggest and try again.

Comment: Unfortunatley, no luck.